# Centre code in Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I would like to centre my code in the Android Studio's/IntelliJ's editor, like as it is done in the Distraction Free Mode.

Right now, it is always aligned on the left side of the editor, but I want to have it in the centre of the window. I could not find any option for this in the settings. Is this possible **without** entering the Distraction Free Mode?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Add `-Deditor.distraction.free.mode=true` in `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options** and restart the IDE. This will center the editor without the other features of the distraction free mode (like hidden tool windows).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: A restart is needed.

Comment: one extra small thing, is that line numbers are aligned on the right side, it would be nice to have them right at the code side, do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Currently distraction free mode is listed in the keymap bindings and you can just assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: @Ixx this question/answer is not about the normal distraction free mode that is accessible via the menu or shortcut.

Comment: Ah right. Well, maybe my comment helps someone. I was looking for just enabling distraction free mode.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work for Idea 2020.2. I've added that parameter, restarted but the text is still aligned to the left.

Upd. I did `exit distraction mode` and then again `enable distraction mode` and it works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks so much!! that saved me!

Comment: @mloureiro It is not possible according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591372/how-to-move-lines-number-position-in-rider)

Comment: This also works really well in the Pycharm IDE, and I've found a way to move the line numbers closer to the code @mloureiro - by opening / pinning the Project tab on the left side. Although it does move the code slightly to the right (off-centre), the gap between the line numbers and code is greatly reduced. I realise this doesn't solve the problem entirely, but is something else to try at least. I'm not sure if this will be the same with other IDEs, but it might be an idea to try pinning or moving things about to see if it effects the horizontal position of the line numbers.

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 29):

You can also activate this option through the registry:

1. Type `shift shift` to search everywhere
2. Type `registry` and select "Registry..."
3. Type `distraction` to filter the list
4. Check the box for "editor.distraction.free.mode"
5. Close the registry

Voilà, no restart needed.

Comment: This is a better solution than the above, IMHO.