# How to move line's number position in Rider?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

I'm using Rider [distraction free mode as described in this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000697904-Center-align-editor-code-outside-of-distraction-free) and I would like to move the line number closer to the green bar because it is a little troublesome to know which line number a certain piece of code is.

[image]

*EDIT*: I want the block of code to be in the center.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have the code centered and the line numbers displayed next to the centered code, please [vote for the corresponding feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243735).

It's only possible to move the code to the left so that it's closer to the line numbers:

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Advanced Settings | **Left margin in distraction free mode**: 0.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want my code to be centered and not on the left.

Comment: There is no way to do it, sorry.